# ggplot2 how to add different sets of colour palettes to different geom_ribbon?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot two types of time-series graphs. One in which the 'min-max' ribbon  is more transparent than the '10th-90h percentile' ribbon, but the colour is region-specific. In the other graph, I wish the colour of the ribbons to be both region and ribbon type specific. Could someone kindly help me? I'm adding below some code of a failed attempt to play with transparency (playing with alpha values doesn't really change the figure the way I'd expect)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
cbPalette <- c("red", "blue")

test <- data.frame(time=c("2018-04-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-06-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-31", "2018-09-30", "2018-04-30", "2018-05-31", "2018-06-30", "2018-07-31", "2018-08-31", "2018-09-30"), 
                   region=c("regionA","regionA","regionA","regionA","regionA","regionA", "regionB","regionB","regionB","regionB","regionB","regionB"),
                   minvalue=c(50, 70, 73, 97, 80, 65, 50, 70, 73, 97, 80, 65), 
                   maxvalue=c(70, 100, 100, 100, 90, 70, 70, 100, 100, 100, 90, 70), 
                   value90th=c(60, 90, 80, 98, 85, 69, 60, 90, 80, 98, 85, 69),
                   value10th=c(60, 80, 75, 97, 84, 67,60, 80, 75, 97, 84, 67),
                   addvalue=c(60, 80, 75, 50, 84, 67,60, 60, 75, 97, 84, 67))

p <- ggplot(test, aes(x=as.POSIXct(time)))
p <- p + facet_grid(region~.)
p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = value10th, ymax = value90th, fill=region, alpha = 0.7))  
p <- p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = minvalue, ymax = maxvalue, fill=region, alpha = 0.6))+ scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y=addvalue, colour="pink"), size=0.5) 
p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is probably in  scale_color_manual and scale_fill_manual.

In a graph I have with multiple facets I had:

```
p <- p + 
  geom_smooth(method = "glm", method.args = list(family = "gaussian"), formula = y ~ 
poly(log(x), 3, raw=TRUE), se=TRUE, alpha = 0.3,aes(fill = Treatment)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","dashed","dotted")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Col[4],Col[3], Col[2])) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Col[4],Col[3], Col[2]))
```

Maybe you can add alpha to scale_fill_manual as a list to give different alpha values to different ribbons.